# Ignore null and get full result

Tags: linq, null

I have below linq select coding. The result become empty if db.actions.ACTC_DBID values are null. How to avoid that. I need to get the query result with null values.

```
var apList = (from r in db.components
                              join o in db.cmp_actionpanel on r.CMP_DBID equals o.CMP_DBID
                              join u in db.cmp_button on o.BTN_DBID equals u.BTN_DBID
                              join a in db.actions on o.ACTC_DBID equals a.ACTC_DBID
                              where (r.ORG_DBID == org && r.CMP_DBID == id)
                              orderby o.ORDER_IDX
                              select new
                              {
                                  AP_DBID = o.AP_DBID,
                                  CMP_NAME = r.CMP_NAME,
                                  CMP_DBID = r.CMP_DBID,
                                  BTN_NAME = u.BTN_NAME,
                                  BTN_DBID = u.BTN_DBID,
                                  ORDER_IDX = o.ORDER_IDX,
                                  ALWAYS_VISIBLE = o.ALWAYS_VISIBLE,
                                  ACTC_DBID = a.ACTC_DBID,
                                  ACTION_CODE = a.ACTION_CODE,
                                  ACTION_CMP_DBID = o.ACTION_CMP_DBID,
                                  STARTS_JOB_PROGRESSION = o.STARTS_JOB_PROGRESSION,
                                  VISIBLE_ON = o.VISIBLE_ON,
                                  CAPTURE_INFO = o.CAPTURE_INFO,
                                  COMMAND = o.COMMAND
                              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var apList = (from r in db.components
                              join o in db.cmp_actionpanel on r.CMP_DBID equals o.CMP_DBID
                              join u in db.cmp_button on o.BTN_DBID equals u.BTN_DBID
                              join a in db.actions on o.ACTC_DBID equals a.ACTC_DBID into aGroup
                              where (r.ORG_DBID == org && r.CMP_DBID == id)
                              orderby o.ORDER_IDX
                              from ag in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new
                              {
                                  AP_DBID = o.AP_DBID,
                                  CMP_NAME = r.CMP_NAME,
                                  CMP_DBID = r.CMP_DBID,
                                  BTN_NAME = u.BTN_NAME,
                                  BTN_DBID = u.BTN_DBID,
                                  ORDER_IDX = o.ORDER_IDX,
                                  ALWAYS_VISIBLE = o.ALWAYS_VISIBLE,
                                  ACTC_DBID = ag.ACTC_DBID == null ? (int?)null : ag.ACTC_DBID,
                                  ACTION_CODE = ag.ACTION_CODE,
                                  ACTION_CMP_DBID = o.ACTION_CMP_DBID,
                                  STARTS_JOB_PROGRESSION = o.STARTS_JOB_PROGRESSION,
                                  VISIBLE_ON = o.VISIBLE_ON,
                                  CAPTURE_INFO = o.CAPTURE_INFO,
                                  COMMAND = o.COMMAND
                              }).ToList();
```